# How to set globals for js2-mode?

Tags: js2-mode

Js2-mode is showing error when there are not registered globals. I've try this code:

```
(defun js2-hook ()
  ;; setting symbols instead of strings also don't work
  (dolist (global '("angular" "$" "jQuery" "console" "_" "window" "setTimeout"))
    (add-to-list 'js2-additional-externs global)))

(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'js2-hook)
```

but this don't work. How can I set globals, setting js2-additional-externs directly don't work also, because describe-variable says that this variable is automatically local when set.

Comment: Have you tried setting `js2-global-externs`? It seems that it's the variable you're looking for.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the variable you want to set is `js2-global-externs`.

`js2-additional-externs` is intended for setting globals on per-buffer basis, not for all buffers with `js2-mode`.